# Alternate command prompt or console application for running Ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, console

The simple black-and-white interface for running Ruby scripts on the standard Windows command prompt is somewhat hard to read without some sort of color scheme interface like in Sublime (especially while debugging). Is there a better, alternate command prompt or console application that will help?

Answer (score 1):

Color scheme will not take effect unless the output is colored. Syntax highlighting can also not be applied because the output is just a string, and is not following the syntax of some language.

Whether the output is colored is thus up to the script you are running. Most console applications are capable of displaying colors. In order to color the terminal output, embedding VT-100 escape sequences in the output string is the standard (and probably the only) way. If it is difficult to do that manually, there are some gems that help you do it.